# Add a second subtitle row to UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have already made a custom class with the init:

```
if(self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifier]) {
}
```

As I wanted to add a blue texted label to the right hand side of the cell and have it go right when selected otherwise it looked odd when highlighted:

```
self.sizeTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width-110, 0.0, 100.0, 44.0)];
self.sizeTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
self.sizeTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.sizeTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:81/255.0 green:102/255.0 blue:145/255.0 alpha:1.0];
self.sizeTextLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.contentView addSubview:self.sizeTextLabel];
```

There is probably a better way of doing that ^

What I would like to do is add another label that is effectively another subtitle row, I then increase the height of the row when the cell is created with the heightForRowAtIndexpath method.

**Problem: When I add a new label 'row' to the content view, it does not get higher (the default views shift to the middle of the view). How do I create and position it correctly below the subtitle view? If I were to change the first subtitle to multiline it would be nice if the second label knew what to do.**

**I wish cocoa had relative positioning. Or I haven't found it yet!**

Answer (score 2):

You can make the detail text label multi line and add your two strings to the one label. In this example, my data has three keys in its dictionaries, "main" for the main label text, and "detail1 and "detail2" for the two subtitle strings.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = object[@"main"];
    NSString *concat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",object[@"detail1"],object[@"detail2"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = concat;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I did consider this but it falls short when a 'subtitle' is too long and needs truncating or goes onto a second line where a slightly wider gap between the two subtitles is required to make clear they are separate.

Comment: @Vanthel, you can always put a space between the lines if you want, and set numberOfLines to 0 which allows unlimited number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom cell with interface builder and use it instead of UITableViewCell.

Check this: http://www.backslashtraining.com/blog/2012/3/10/ios-5-tip-of-the-week-custom-table-view-cells.html